# problems with "How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows"

Tags: installation, usb, windows

I'm looking at 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

it's a really long time since I've used linux, but to me this is unclear, I've downloaded the app from Pen Drive Linux, but then when I use it, in step two it says "Click 'Browse' and open the downloaded ISO file." but at no point has it told me to download an iso file, or given a link to where I download it from.

The one given in the picture is called precise-desktop.iso, I've no idea if that's the file I'm supposed to be downloading, or if I need to rename the file to this, or if I just need to download a regular ubuntu distribution, which is what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot is just an example. The iso file that it is referring to is the Ubuntu distribution that you want to make bootable on this USB stick. So yes, just download a regular Ubuntu distribution from the [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download an Ubuntu ISO file from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Then you open Pen Drive Linux, choose which version of Ubuntu you downloaded, and point the interface to the file.

It will ask if you want to allocate space (I forget what its called) to the usb. you don't need to do this if you are just going ahead and installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

On step 1: you can choose the distribution of Ubuntu, and also check the "Download the ISO" box to download the ISO file with the help of pen drive automatically.

On step 2: this step is for .iso files which has been dowloaded earlier from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and saved to your computer.

13.04 is the recent distro.
12.04 is the Long Term Support distro.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download Open this link and download linux live usb creator. Open linux live and follow the instructions.

Step 1: Select your usb key.
   Step 2:Choose "Download".(It will ask
   to select a folder)
Step 3:Leave this step as it is.
Step 4:Tick
   on first and second box.(Remember to back up your key before
   proceeding  to  next step.)
Step 5:Click on the lighting icon and
   wait for it to finish. Your key is now ready.

---